# form validation redirection problems

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

Hi i am adding comments on a post using django, im saving the information directly in the database , this operates successfuly, but after submitting the post it suppose to redirect on the same page with the comment but, the form keep on resubmitting help please?

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form = CommentForm()

        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-date_created')

        context = {
            'post':post,
            'form': form,
            'comments': comments
        }
        return render(request, 'my_news/post_detail.html', context )
    
    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.name = request.user
            new_post.post= post
            new_post.save()

        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-date_created')

        context = {
            'post':post,
            'form': form,
            'comments':comments
        }
        return render(request, 'my_news/post_detail.html', context )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form sent through the context contains the data of the previous posted comment. If you want to show an empty form, you have to use an empty one.

```
context = {
    'post': post,
    'form': CommentForm(),
    'comments': comments
}
```

I hope I understood your question properly

Comment: Yes it worked properly thank you very much!

Comment: if it helped, you can accept my answer ;-)